# Why can't I paste more than 6 characters into a UITextField in an UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uialertview

I have UITextField in an UIAlertView.

When I copy and paste 6 characters into the alert view textfield it works fine, but when I paste more than 6 it doesn't work.

How can I solve this?

```
-(IBAction)btnForgotPasswordHandler:(id)sender{
    cancelbtnPressed = NO;
    self.alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Skribbee" message:@"Please input your email address to proceed!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
    [self.alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    tfLostPassword=[alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    tfLostPassword.delegate = self;
    [tfLostPassword setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
    [tfLostPassword setPlaceholder:@"Email Address"];
    tfLostPassword.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyGo;
    [self.alert show];
}
```

Comment: k i have accepted the old answers i didn't know about this thing......now please can i get help for this question thx

Comment: 1 thing its 8 characters not 6 characters in question